# Out of memory while deploying chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

While executing `./network.sh deployCC` of the test-network Hyperledger Fabric sample, I get an "out of memory" fatal error.  I am currently on an AWS Lightsail VPS instance of 512 MB RAM, 1 vCPU, 20 GB SSD.  What is the recommended hardware requirements?

k

Comment: It's not gonna work with that much memory. `512 MB` is too low. Even vCPU's aren't enough.

Comment: What is the recommendation?

Comment: Atleast 4 Gb Memory, 4 vCPU's. Performance of Peer and orderer nodes somehow directly proportional to configuration of a machine.

Comment: Currently I'm using 4Gb Memory and 4vCPU per node.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To run Hyperledger Composer and Hyperledger Fabric, we recommend you have at least 4Gb of memory.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/installing/installing-prereqs